# Option text doesn't change accordingly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

The problem I'm facing is that whenever I upload a file from the second row, it changes the textfield of the first row. It doesn't seem to update the second row accordingly

```
<form action="Fruits" method="Post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table id="myTable">
    <c:forEach items="${fruits}" var="val" varStatus="count">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Fruit</th>
      <th>Color</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="${val.name}"></td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control dropdown" id="color" name="color">
          <option id="colors">${val.color}</option>
        </select>
        <input type="file" id="image" var="image" value="image"/>
        <label for="image" value="Upload">Upload</label>
      </td>
    </tbody>
    </c:forEach>
    </table>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default json-editor-btn-add" onclick="myFunction()">Add</button>
</form>
```

So whenever I want to update a new file under my second row, upon clicking on 'Upload', it updates the text for the first row rather than the second row. This are my JSP codes function. Please do assist me on this

```
$(function () {
        $('input[type=file]').change(function () {
            var t = $(this).val();
            var file_name = t.substr(12, t.length);
            var labelText = 'File : ' + t.substr(12, t.length);
            document.getElementById("colors").innerHTML = file_name;
            $(this).prev('label').text(labelText);
            $(this).prev('label').css({
                "color": "black"
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.
This is not a JAVA question but a jQuery and HTML question. Post the rendered HTML in the snippet. But I can already tell you that IDs need to be unique.  You even have the same ID in the options as in the select

Comment: @mplungjan Hi I'm new to this, I know the problem has to do with having the same ID.. But I do not know how to solve the problem

Comment: SO: click [edit], then `[<>]` and post a [mcve] of RELEVANT HTML and JavaScript plus frameworks

Comment: I see a <c:forEach - so it is a loop, but I do not see where the loop ends

Comment: @mplungjan Just editied. Do assist me in this

Comment: There is no element with id ```colors``` in your example. Also, your ```select``` and ```option``` BOTH have the id ```color```. IDs are meant to be unique for a multitude of reasons.

Comment: Click [edit], then click the button that looks like `[<>]` and paste RENDERED HTML, not JSP (view-source in browser) plus relevant script and frameworks (jQuery, bootstrap etc) from a CDN

Comment: @cruzzy You label comes after the input not before, so i think you need to use `$(this).next('label')`. Also it seems a bit strange you foreach the entity content of the table and not just inside the tbody

Comment: @Shrimp both have different ID, the problem is that the loop will display multiple rows, but the problem lies where I can't seem to update the 2nd row after i press the upload button. It changes the first row

Comment: The part that is not updating the current row *and* updating a different row is `document.getElementById("colors").innerHTML` - as noted, IDs must be unique - but unique *across the entire document*, not just different element types (`select` vs `option`) and not just in the current row.  The browser sees **only one** element with ID=colors and it's in the first row.   You're already using jquery with .prev etc, so: `$(this).closest("td").find("select>option").text(labelText)` should suffice.

Comment: Though a drop down with only one entry is not good UX.  Did you mean to add a new "colour" each time?

Comment: @freedomn-m it doesnt change, it still change the textfield in the first row. I tried to upload a file from the second row but instead of changing the textfield in the second row it changes the first.

Comment: "The text field"?  Which "text field"?  There's an `input type="text" name="name" id="name"` which your code, *as provided*, doesn't touch and a `select id=color` and `select id=colors` which your code *does* change.

Comment: @freedomn-m So example I want to add a new color by uploading a new image file on the second row. I know that its because of the same ID that is why it always changes the first row. So I'm not sure if there is a solution to this.

Comment: @freedomn-m the texst field as in under the option tag, it should replace the name of the file i just uploaded

Comment: @cruzzy PLEASE update your QUESTION with RUNNING code and update the description with expected behaviour instead of just commenting

Comment: Then you did it wrong - making the change I suggested above works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/18ypLerb/

Comment: @freedomn-m Sorry to confuse you, its "option text". But do you understand what I'm trying to explain

Comment: Did you check the fiddle above?

Answer (score -1):

```
Change the code to 
<form action="Fruits" method="Post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table id="myTable">
<c:forEach items="${fruits}" var="val" varStatus="count">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Fruit</th>
  <th>Color</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <td><input type="text" name="name[]" id="name" value="${val.name}"></td>
  <td>
    <select class="form-control dropdown" id="color" name="color[]">
      <option id="color">${val.color}</option>
    </select>
    <input type="file" id="image" var="image" name="image[]" value="image"/>
    <label for="image" value="Upload">Upload</label>
  </td>
</tbody>
</c:forEach>
</table>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default json-editor-btn-add" onclick="myFunction()">Add</button>
```

Comment: This is not a PHP question.

Comment: For future reference: please do describe what changes you've made in the code - at first glance this looks identical.  See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers#:~:text=%22This%20code%20may%20answer%20the,%22or%22%20without%20losing%20meaning.

Comment: @freedomn-m I see [] php array notation on the name which is neither relevant nor helpful